# Convert List of data.frame in R to list of doubles

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list in R that looks like this (dput):

[image]

```
list(AAA = structure(list(Point = " -11.742 , -1.552 , 1.307 , 27.407 , 47.635 , 40.457 , 40.457 , 44.573 , 24.345 , -7.879 , -19.874 , -23.991 "), row.names = "AAA", class = "data.frame"), 
    BBB = structure(list(Point = " -11.742 , -1.552 , 1.307 , 27.407 , 35.801 , 28.622 , 4.954 , -2.764 , -11.158 , -19.713 , -23.946 , -16.228 , -0.704 , 2.826 , 7.059 "), row.names = "BBB", class = "data.frame"), 
    CCC = structure(list(Point = " -11.742 , -1.552 , 1.307 , 27.407 , 35.801 , 28.622 , 4.954 , -2.764 , -11.158 , -19.713 , -23.946 , -16.228 , -0.704 , -7.437 , -3.204 , -23.729 , -32.812 , -26.078 , -10.252 , -11.421 , -2.338 "), row.names = "CCC", class = "data.frame"), 
    DDD = structure(list(Point = " -11.742 , -1.552 , 1.307 , 27.407 , 35.801 , 28.622 , 4.954 , -2.764 , -11.158 , -19.713 , -23.946 , -16.228 , -0.704 , 2.826 , 7.059 "), row.names = "DDD", class = "data.frame"))
```

I need it to look like this (dput):

[image]

```
list(AAA = c(-11.742, -1.552, 1.307, 27.407, 47.635, 40.457, 
40.457, 44.573, 24.345, -7.879, -19.874, 23.991), BBB = c(-11.742, 
-1.551, 1.308, 27.407, 35.801, 28.623, 4.954, -2.764, -11.158, 
-19.713, -23.946, -16.228, -0.704, 2.826, 7.059), CCC = c(-11.742, 
-1.551, 1.308, 27.407, 35.801, 28.623, 4.954, -2.764, -11.158, 
-19.713, -23.946, -16.228, -0.704, -7.437, -3.204, -23.729, -32.812, 
-26.078, -10.252, -11.421, -2.338), D = c(-11.742, -1.551, 1.308, 
27.407, 35.801, 28.623, 4.954, -2.764, -11.158, -19.713, -23.946, 
-16.228, -0.704, 2.826, 7.059))
```

I have tried using as.double to change the datatype for the column but I have not yet hit the right code to get this done.  How can I convert this?

Comment: @RonakShah  I added the dput version to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element in the list split the string on comma, remove whitespace and convert the data to numeric.

```
list_data <- lapply(list_data, function(x) 
                    as.numeric(trimws(strsplit(x$Point, ',\\s*')[[1]])))
list_data
```

[image]

Comment: Works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using `scan` as below:

```
lapply(df, function(x)scan(text=x$Point, sep=",", quiet = TRUE))

$AAA
 [1] -11.742  -1.552   1.307  27.407  47.635  40.457  40.457  44.573  24.345  -7.879 -19.874 -23.991

$BBB
 [1] -11.742  -1.552   1.307  27.407  35.801  28.622   4.954  -2.764 -11.158 -19.713 -23.946 -16.228  -0.704
[14]   2.826   7.059

$CCC
 [1] -11.742  -1.552   1.307  27.407  35.801  28.622   4.954  -2.764 -11.158 -19.713 -23.946 -16.228  -0.704
[14]  -7.437  -3.204 -23.729 -32.812 -26.078 -10.252 -11.421  -2.338

$DDD
 [1] -11.742  -1.552   1.307  27.407  35.801  28.622   4.954  -2.764 -11.158 -19.713 -23.946 -16.228  -0.704
[14]   2.826   7.059
```